# GraphQL and ReactJS state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I use `ApolloProvider` as HOC to fetch data from server and `Query` from `'react-apollo'` to render data on pages and in components.

And here is issue. `<Query />` renders data directly to elements such as `<input />` without using component's state. But what if I want to change `<input />` value with `onChange()` function, where do I store new values?
Is it possible to fetch data with Apollo in `componentDidMount()`, save it and then pass it to `render()`?

Here is dummy code I have, just for an example:

```
const USER = id => gql`
  {
    user(id: "${id}") {
      _id
      name
      surname
      email
    }
  }
`;

render() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    return (
      <Query query={USER(id)}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (error) return <p>Error:(</p>;

          const { user } = data;

          return (
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={user.name} />
              <input type="text" value={user.surname} />
              <input type="text" value={user.email} />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
```

I want to add `onChange()` function to these inputs and then do a GraphQL mutation

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap a `Mutation` around your query (or the opposite, it would not change anything). And then bind the `onChange` functions of your inputs the the `Mutation` action.

```
<Mutation mutation={UPLOAD_FILE}>
    {action =>
        <Query query={USER(id)}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
                if (error) return <p>Error:(</p>;

                const { user } = data;

                return (
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value={user.name} onChange={ev => action({ variables: { newText: ev.target.value } })} />
                        <input type="text" value={user.surname} onChange={ev => action({ variables: { newText: ev.target.value } })}  />
                        <input type="text" value={user.email} onChange={ev => action({ variables: { newText: ev.target.value } })}  />
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        </Query>
    }
</Mutation>
```

You can also take the logic out of your JSX by binding you result to a function in your class :

```
handleInputChange = (action, type) => ev => {
    action({ variables: { [type]: ev.target.value } })
}

<Mutation mutation={UPLOAD_FILE}>
    {action =>
        <Query query={USER(id)}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
                if (error) return <p>Error:(</p>;

                const { user } = data;

                return (
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value={user.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange(action, 'name')} />
                        <input type="text" value={user.surname} onChange={this.handleInputChange(action, 'surname')}  />
                        <input type="text" value={user.email} onChange={this.handleInputChange(action, 'email')}  />
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        </Query>
    }
</Mutation>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try your example. However it is pretty strange that state is not used to store values, because it is useful in cases when you need to add validation for inputs (e.g. email) and after validation mutate with save button

Comment: Well, in my second example, you can verify is the given input is correct in the `handleInputChange` function, as every changes will pass by it. You can also use what the mutation will return to set your state and make your inputs controlled. Do you need an example ?